# Converting RBG to hex

Tags: c#, hex, rgb

I'm trying to convert an `int` which I get from a database, which is an RBG code (without the formatting e.g  111000111 instead of 111,000,111) and trying to convert it to a hexadecimal number.

Has anyone got an idea how I would do this?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by `111000111`? i.e. what does `111000111` represent? `0x6f 0x00 0x6f`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [FromArgb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zys7833.aspx) method:

```
int number = 111000111;
Color c = Color.FromArgb(number);
string hex = string.Format("{0:x}{1:x}{2:x}", c.R, c.G, c.B);
```

Comment: Are you sure about this?  To me it look like that function takes an ARGB value as argument, which I am not sure is what he has.

Comment: +1 - I think the OP needs to provide more information before you can make the assumptions in this answer.